# How to run a command if ping fails over monit?

Tags: ubuntu, monit

Hi everyone i'm trying to do a CloudFlaire IP failovr with monit

actually i'm using this but unfortunately this strings doesn't look to works when monit runs there is any mistake from my side ?

```
check host x.x.x.x with address x.x.x.x
  if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 3 seconds for 2 cycles then exec "/bin/bash -c /etc/monit/SecondaryIP.sh"
  else if succeeded for 2 cycles then exec "/bin/bash -c /etc/monit/NativeIP.sh"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, your sample looks good.

```
check host Testhost with address 192.168.1.6
#  if failed ping4 count 3 with timeout 3 seconds for 2 cycles then exec "/usr/local/etc/monit/scripts/script.sh"
  if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 3 seconds for 2 cycles then exec "/usr/local/etc/monit/scripts/script.sh"
     else if succeeded for 2 cycles then exec "/usr/local/etc/monit/scripts/script.sh"
```

As long as you start Monit in a "root" environment, every thing works well. A snippet from the monit.log file.

```
'Testhost' ping test succeeded [response time 5.046 ms]
'Testhost' exec: '/usr/local/etc/monit/scripts/script.sh'

'Testhost' ping test failed
'Testhost' exec: '/usr/local/etc/monit/scripts/script.sh'
```

You should check your monit.log and the used scripts. Try "ping4" instead of "icmp type echo" in your test.